# Is it suitable to use 'etc.' in an academic paper?

Tags: abbreviations, formality

I'm writing one of my first academic papers and I'm not sure whether *etc.* is too informal. Should I use *et cetera* instead?

Comment: I think Writers.SE might be able to help you more with this question, since it's more about style than usage.

Comment: Go with *et cetera* when it is not sentence-ending, to avoid the ugly period after *etc*.

Comment: @Kat: only the most pretentious and unedited academic writers would use the full spelling of these abbreviations. Sorry, I mean to say that -no one- uses the full spelling.

Comment: @Mitch: My supervisor tells me that "etc." is too informal for scientific writing. Funny thing though, when I searched the 'web for scientific style guides, all three that I found used it profusely, without mentioning guidelines for its use. :D

Comment: @naught101: I agree that 'etc.' is too informal. My point was to Kaz that one should definitely not spell it out as 'et cetera'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***etc.*** is not informal. In fact it is better than its expansion, which sounds rather awkward. It is perfectly ok to use *etc.* in an academic paper.

Just note, however, that both of them are very sparingly and carefully used in serious writing. Try to list fully or describe the list instead.

Comment: For better advice, migrate the Q. to writersSE and see.

Comment: What do you mean that *et cetera* **sounds** awkward compared to *etc*? Are you referring to the "ee tee cee" pronuncation? Otherwise, they do not make a different sound.

Comment: Right, it sounds the same, but it *looks* awkward.

Answer (score 15):

I would recommend not using *etc.* in an academic paper. And if you do, please be sure you are using it correctly. See this [good explanation](http://www.arcticllama.com/blog/writing-tips/grammar/etc-et-al-ap-style-writing/) about using *etc.* Here's an excerpt:

> It isn’t that writing that contains *et al.* or *etc.* is bad writing, it’s just that it is completely possible to construct meaningful sentences without using them. In fact, in most cases, it is probably preferable not to use them since both are badly overused, and technically speaking, they have definite meanings and specific usages that often do not apply in the cases they are used.  More specifically, etc. is NOT to be used to complete a clause that starts with *such as* or *for example*.
>
> To use *etcetera* in a sentence is to imply that the the reader already knows the rest of the set it is referring to, not, as it is so often used, as a placeholder for an undefined set.  (Note that *etc.* is fine to use when referring to an infinite set, which is, by definition, a known set.)

As an editor, I would almost always ask for a revision of a sentence that contains *etc.* It usually can be reworded more precisely and better without using this word. And quite honestly, many authors use it incorrectly.

Comment: AP style is for media writing, not academic writing. I like the point about not using it with e.g., but I'm not sure that I could find a rational argument to support it. You could have a sentence "for example, apples, oranges, bananas and so on", couldn't you? Why is that bad, other than sounding a little awkward? Also, "an infinite set" is *certainly not* always a known set.

Comment: We use AP style in our clinical journal (or at least our style guide is based on it). I think saying "for example,...and so on" is redundant. What follows are examples, not intended to be a complete list. I'm not sure about the "infinite set." That point was made in the excerpt, wasn't mine.

Comment: Yes; I've come across a university style guide strongly advising eschewing the use of _all_ 'Latin' abbreviations.

Answer (score 7):

I think the problem is not the phrase itself, but the fact that it assumes the reader will know what "the rest" is. As a rule, in academic papers, this is a difficult assumption to make, because the nature of an academic paper is to define and spell out information.

So if it is appropriate to include this at all, then the expression "etc." is fine - it is not the formality that is the issue, but the implications.

Comment: Nice argument. What about when it doesn't matter if the audience knows the rest of the set?

Comment: +1. This is the reason it is better to expand fully or describe the list.

Comment: @naught101 - I have been trying to think of a case where this would be appropriate. Given that it is an academic paper, the list should normally be expanded or have a group title ( "or any other 2D shapes" ). etc. always leaves some ambiguity, which is rarely appropriate for such a medium. FWIW, I am currently writing a PhD thesis, and have not found a place for etc anywhere in it.

Comment: I have one: the list of components in a climate model: "cloud formation processes, soil water run-off, sea-ice model, etc." There is potentially no end to the list, but it doesn't matter to the reader. The list is just to give the reader an idea of what kind of processes we're talking about. I guess I could use "for example ...", but I don't see why that's any better.

Answer (score 5):

Garner in *Garner's Modern American Usage* has a good entry on this. He says:

> Writers should generally try to be as specific as
>   possible rather than make use of this term. Still, it would be foolish to prohibit *etc.* outright because often one simply
>   *cannot* practicably list all that should be listed in a given context.
>   Hence, rather than convey to the reader that a list is seemingly
>   complete when it is not, the writer might justifiably use *etc.* (**always the
>   abbreviation**). In text, a substitute such as *and others* is usually
>   a better choice.
>
> The term *etc.* should be reserved for things, not for
>   people.

Comment: I'm not sure whether to fix misspelled *simply* or flag for unattributed quote from Garner's Modern American Usage; got any thoughts?

Comment: Try to search Garner's Modern American Usage on Google Books; or try with this link (http://books.google.com/books?id=mVcJqKs1isUC&printsec=frontcover&dq=garner&hl=it&sa=X&ei=CkqdT_uPCsrl4QTltfGpDg&redir_esc=y#v=snippet&q=%22The%20new%20yorker%22&f=false) that function from Italy, but I  do not think  that function from others countries.

Comment: A [google search](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22+list+is+seemingly+complete%22&btnG=) provides six links all more relevant than that in your comment, which shows "New Yorker" references in Garner.  But the link is not the important issue. The important issue is that you should attribute the quotation, instead of displaying it like original writing.

Comment: @jwpat7 - Done.

Comment: @jwpat7 - Pardon! - The preceding link was referred to this answer http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66126/what-is-the-standard-rule-for-using-or-not-using-hyphen-and-diaeresis-on-the-wor/66152#66152

Comment: Garner's isn't specific to academic writing though, so it might be debatable how applicable this answer is..

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 'et cetera'  it seems more formal and my teachers taught me not to abbreviate on test and important documents.

Comment: Hello, Lexi. Do what your teachers say until you're no longer under their authority. But then you can explore the facts for yourself. One university style guide I've come across requires that _etc_, _et al_ etc should not be used at all. But others differ. Any 'rules' about this are local style preferences rather than binding requirements common to the English language.