# Use of 'And more' to end a list

Tags: grammar, lists

Can I conclude a list with 'And more' because a platform offers numerous features, and listing them all there will make it ineffective? The items aren't a grocery list where the user will not have the idea what the 'more' refers to.

This list is to emphasize the features of a platform, so I think we can conclude it using, 'And more'. Here's an example,

> There are other essential features such as:
>
> - Create an admin account.
> - Invite users.
> - Offer tokes.
> - Create a subscription.
> - Change subscription type.
> - Payment reminders.
> - And more.

Or should I not use 'such as' and then use 'And more?'

Comment: Making  "and more" or "etc" a bullet-point would be unusual.  Especially if you're going to refer to the list as "essential features". It's like saying "Critical things to remember:": 1 wear your goggles, 2 make sure your respirator is seated properly, 3 some other critical things

Comment: Once you have said "**such as**", you do not need a comment at the end as "such as" implies that the list is incomplete.

Comment: Yes; using 'etc' or ellipses after an initial 'eg', 'such as' or 'including' is seen as redundancy at least bordering on the unacceptable. The same reasoning applies to 'and more' ... though if using 'and more', 'etc' etc I'd not bullet it along with the individual listed items.

Comment: Are you asking if it is grammatically or semantically correct, or stylistically appropriate (three distinct choices)? One thing that is definitely incorrect is "and more" as one of the bullet points. It should go outside the list of bullet points (if it is used at all).

Answer (score 0):

In English it is traditional to use **etc.** which is short for **et cetera**, Latin for 'and the others' or 'and all the rest'.

I don't think it would be seen as 'wrong' to use *and more*, just a little unusual.

Comment: *Etc* is sometimes considered problematic (it's vague and potentially obscures detail) or its use to be minimised ([see this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66149/is-it-suitable-to-use-etc-in-an-academic-paper)) so the same principle would probably apply to "and more". I don't think you need "and more" or "etc" if you've already used "such as", "including", etc.

Answer (score 0):

As Greybeard notes in a comment beneath the posted question, including the phrase "such as" in the introduction to a list indicates that the items enumerated in the list are not exhaustive. That being the case, listing "and more" as an entry in the list that follows "such as" is redundant.

A more difficult case arises in instances where a writer uses "including," rather than "such as," in the introductory sentence. For example:

> There are other essential features, including the following:

Here, readers can't tell from the introductory wording whether the list is exhaustive or not, since "including" can be read as meaning either "consisting only of" or "consisting of (among others)." If the writer has the latter meaning in mind, including "And more" as the final entry in the list does clarify that point and, therefore, is not technically redundant. Nevertheless, rgew construction may strike some readers as being an inelegant way of conveying the point.

For one thing, "And more" is unlike the previous entries in the list because it is plural and thus points not to one feature but to multiple features, whereas each of the previous entries in the list focuses on a single feature. Moreover, "And more" is extremely vague, whereas the preceding entries are relatively precise. So from the point of view of basic parallelism "And more" is not a good match with the other entries. (Tangentially, I note that the entry "Payment reminders" is out of parallel with the previous five entries, too, because it—like "And more"—doesn't start with a verb. A professionally edited version of the list would probably convert "Payment reminders" to something like "Send payment reminders." Clearly, "And more" doesn't blend seamlessly into a list of entries that consistently start with a verb.)

There are many ways to avoid the redundancy of "features such as x, y, z, and more." The simplest of these, however, is to let "such as" handle the job of indicating that the list that follows is non-exhaustive—which is the plain meaning of "such as"—and to delete "And more" from the end of the list.