# Is the diaeresis legal in “naïve”?

Tags: diacritics, diaeresis

I understand why *naïve* is spelled with two dots, and that those dots are called a diaeresis.

What I do not understand is whether the use of a diaeresis is legal in English; is it?

Other than *naïve*, I am hard pressed to come up with another example of a word that uses a diaeresis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course it is “legal”.  The *Oxford English Dictionary* includes all these words with either diaereses or umlauts in them:

> achroö-, aïoli, Ångström (unit), arsinoïtherium, Aufklärer, Aufklärung, bastnäsite, beënt, Boötes, Böttger, bratwürste,bröggerite, Brontëan, Brontëana, Brontëism, Brückner, cacoëpistic, cacoëpy, caïque, caïquejee, Chün, cinnameïn, Danaïdean,
>   denkmäler, dzongpön, einfühlung, Eötvös, epiploön, faröelite, faux-naïf, flügelhorn, föhn, fräulein, Fröbel, Fröhlich, Führer,gefüllte fish, gemütlich, Gemütlichkeit, Gestaltqualität, glögg, glühwein, Gödel, Gödelian, Gödel(’s) theorem, Götterdämmerung,
>   gräben, Grübelsucht, grünauite, grünerite, grünlingite, gümbelite, Günz, hälleflinta, hälleflintoid, haüyne, haüynite, haüynophyr,
>   heröa, heröon, heveëne, hexaëmeron, hübnerite, hügelite, hühnerkobelite, hydantoïn, hyperoödon, Identitätsphilosophie, jäger,kaïd, kämmererite, kësterite, Klebs-Löffler, knödel, kochubeïte, kulturträger, kümmel, Kümmell’s disease, Künstlerroman, Kuo-yü,
>   lagerstätte, lagerstätten, Länder, ländler, langue d’oïl, Laocoön, lekë, Lieberkühn, Lieberkühnian, löllingite, löweite, löwigite,lünebergite, Lung-ch’üan, märchen, Marie-Strümpell, Marinesco-Sjögren syndrome, mässig, Meistersänger, Meistersängers, melopoeïa,
>   microaërophilous, mitteleuropäisch, Möbius, Moët, monoïdeism, Mössbauer, muisvoël, Müller, müller, Müllerian, Müller-Lyer,
>   Müller’s larva, Müller-Thurgau, naïd, naïdes, naïf, naïfly, naïs, naïve, naïvely, naïveness, naïveté, naïvety, nordenskiöldine,onomatopoësis, ouabaïn, panzoöty, penniä, Perrier-Jouët, ploïmate, Plücker, Plückerian, poë-bird, Prägnanz, prosenneëdrous,
>   purpureïn, Qualitätswein, Querflöte, Ragnarök, Reichsführer, rohrflöte, Rörstrand, rötheln, rumänite, salonfähig, Salpausselkä,
>   salpingo-oöphorectomy, salpingo-oöphoritis, Sängerfest, Schabzieger Käse, Schätzi, Schimpfwörter, Schiötz, schmierkäse, Schönlein,schröckingerite, Schröder, Schrödinger (wave, ψ-) function, Schrödinger, Schrödinger(’s) (wave) equation, Schüller-Christian,
>   Schutzbündler, schwärm, schwärmer, schwärmerei, schwärmerin, schwärmerisch, Sjögren, sjögrenite, Sörensen, Spätlese, Spätzle,
>   Spielräume, Spitzflöte, Spörer, Spörer minimum, Spörer’s law, Sprachgefühl, Standartenführer, staphisaïne, Steinhäger, strüverite,
>   Sturmbannführer, tetraëterid, tetrastoön, thebaïcine, Thebaïd, thebaïne, thebaïsm, thymoïl, thymoïlamide, Töpler, triacontaëterid,trögerite, Türkmen, über alles, Überfremdung, überhaupt, Übermensch, übermenschlich, Übermenschlichkeit, ulvöspinel, väyrynenite,
>   Versöhnung, Volapük, Volapüker, Völkerwanderung, Völkerwanderungen, völkisch, Vöslauer, wabaïn, Waldenström, Wandervögel,Widmanstätten, Wöhler, wölsendorfite, Wörter und Sachen, Würm, Würmian, Würtemberg siphon, Württemberger, wüstite, xanthoxyloïn,
>   yüeh, Yüeh, yüeh ch’in, Zöllner.

Comment: +1 Thank you.  That being said, most of these words do not appear in mainstream usage as often as naive.  And some are just transferred over from the original usage in the source language, such as Türkmen.

Comment: @Sabuncu You should definitely see [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/66160/2085) here. You can still click the outlined checkmark on this current question to accept it even though it is marked as a duplicate. They may merge it later, though.

Comment: Adding umlauts to an answer about diaereses is wantonly confusing; the former indicate a foreign origin  in writing (and may or may not affect pronunciation in English), while the latter affect pronunciation but are effectively optional in writing.

Comment: @TimLymington I’m well aware of the difference, but I could think of no simple way to grep out which is which. I think the questioner was really just asking whether using those two little dots above is legal in English. You will note that Unicode does even have a separate code point for an umlaut that is distinct from a diaeresis, and the OED does not encode those differently either.

Comment: Yes Tim you are right, I was asking about the affects on pronunciation.  Even if it is optional, is it "recognized" as a legal part of the English language?  Of course, this leads to the question, who decides what is legal in the English language.

Comment: @Sabuncu Yes, of course it is “legal” — whatever that means. Those are all from the OED, which documents what people actually use.

Comment: @tchrist, thank you. OED is the source, then. (I have a lot to learn!)

Comment: Has Noël been cancelled?

Comment: Good one Edwin!  And Season's Greetings to you. ;-)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Noël Coward has, Noël Edmunds nearly has, and Noël Gallagher is in hiding.

Comment: Looks like I am a renegade if coöperate and coördinate are not in the OED