# Re-condition vs recondition in statistical text

Tags: hyphenation

I write an article which is talking about conditional probabilities. Each probability  is *conditioned* on something (some *condition*). Then, in the following sentence, I am talking about changing this underlying condition:

> We introduce a biologically more meaningful parametrization of
> residency probability, and then **re-condition** this probability to
> newly captured individuals.

In this context, should I use "re-condition" or "recondition"? My instinct was to use re-condition, because it emphasizes the connection with "condition" as the probabilistic conditioning... rather than evoking the other unrelated meanings, which the word "recondition" has.

Comment: I wouldn't use either. The word "recondition" has the established meaning ***overhaul or repair***. Trying to shoe-horn it into meaning ***alter the conditions / constraints of** [some test, or whatever]* is asking too much. That's even allowing for the fact that introducing a non-standard hyphen *might* alert the reader that you intend a "special" sense (you could also use "scare quotes" for the same purpose). But I suggest you just say "change the conditions" or similar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hyphens in verb construction containing prefix such as "re"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84855/hyphens-in-verb-construction-containing-prefix-such-as-re) Stoney B includes << Usually you can just slap re on the front of a word, without a hyphen, and you will be understood. [BUT] 
 There are circumstances in which the hyphen is desirable:

... (2)  If you want to draw attention to the fact that you are using a “re” word in a different sense than that which would be expected, particularly if you are reverting to the base sense. [+ example] >>