# Hyphen for re when doing again

Tags: orthography, technical

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hyphens in verb construction containing prefix such as “re”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84855/hyphens-in-verb-construction-containing-prefix-such-as-re)
>   [Adding a prefix "re" to a word, with or without a hyphen?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7731/adding-a-prefix-re-to-a-word-with-or-without-a-hyphen)

I have a question about the use of the prefix 're', that means 'do it again' in my context. Let me explain: in mathematics we use the concept of 'parameterized' objects, that is, objects obtained while some parameter varies (think of the parameter as the time and the object as a point moving on a plane).

Well, if we describe the movement using the parameter we say that **we are parameterizing** or **the object is parameterized**. So, if we change the parameter by another one (for example, change the speed of the clock) we say that **we are reparameterizing**  the object.

This is my question: Which is better: **reparameterized** or **re-parameterized**? I've just found [this discussion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7731/adding-a-prefix-re-to-a-word-with-or-without-a-hyphen) but I remain uncertain.

Comment: Also this discussion: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84855/hyphens-in-verb-construction-containing-prefix-such-as-re  The fact that you can't decide about a debate that's been replayed several times here isn't an excuse for rehearsing it yet again, I think.

Comment: There are two tests for deciding: [english.stackexchange.com/questions/7731](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7731/adding-a-prefix-re-to-a-word-with-or-without-a-hyphen)

Comment: @itsbruce You mean *rehashing*.

Comment: This may be merged with the post cited by @itsbruce -- the issue is not settled in any case.

Comment: @Kris no, I really do mean rehearse.  The older sense of the word is appropriate, here.

Comment: I would suggest that you read this answer http://english.stackexchange.com/a/895/4915 and navigate to  the second URL http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp see the 2nd rule 8, hyphens with prefixes, which specifically addresses your question about use of re with a hyphen.

Comment: @FeralOink Sounds good: "the re means again AND omitting the hyphen would cause confusion with another word." How should you know "would cause confusion" or not? cf. my answer below.

Comment: @StoneyB I'd say it should've been *merged*, not closed.

Comment: @waiwai and mods: I'd say it should've been merged, not closed.

Comment: @Kris Closure is the first step towards a merge.

Answer (score 1):

A pragmatic approach would be to check a standard dictionary.

My rationale is that:
It takes time for words to become mainstream.

Dictionaries rely on usage and popularity.

Certain words incidentally starting with the letters *re* already exist and have definite meanings. We need to be aware of them (e.g. *resent*, *resign*, *report*). Do not write *resent* when you mean *sent again*; write *re-sent*.

Certain words may be defined in standard dictionaries (AmE, BrE as may apply) **with** a hyphen, for good reason. Follow the convention.

In case of a neologism or where the word with the *re* prefix is not listed in dictionaries, **use a hyphen** in consideration for the reader.